# Maximizing the probability of a user subscribing given a price

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, expectation-maximization

So, I was assigned the task outlined below and I have no idea on how to start. I'm a beginner so bear with me.

We have a distribution that represents how much users are connected to a service. Some are connected for 5 minutes, some for 10, some for 8 hours or more. Given the price a connected user costs us per hour I need to come up with a price (for the premium service) that maximizes the revenue. (I personally see this as maximizing the probability of a user subscribing given a price.) The idea is to 'rope in' as many users as possible. Probably the heavy users of the service will get a subscription, however they might cost us more. So ideally the price would be be attractive enough for the medium users of the service so at the end of the day we still end up making a buck.